# greasemonkey: stop embedded JS from running

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A page has the following in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // some code
</script>
```

My greasemonkey script needs to *prevent that script from running*. How can I do this?

---

**Update:** I understand that in the general case this is impossible. However, in my specific case, I may have a loophole?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (!window.devicePixelRatio) {
    // some code that I -don't- want to be run, regardless of the browser
  }
</script>
```

Is there some way I can define `window.devicePixelRatio` before the embedded script runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User scripts run after the page is loaded, so you aren't able to.

Unless, the code uses the "onload" event.

> User scripts are executed after the
>   DOM is fully loaded, but before onload
>   occurs. This means that your scripts
>   can begin immediately and don't need
>   to wait for onload.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll do my best to try and undo what the script does. I've updated the question with something that -may- make it possible... or is it the case that by the time my GM script runs, it's too late anyway?

Comment: Not with a user script. The embedded JavaScript runs as soon as it is loaded by the browser. User scripts run after the entire page is loaded.

Answer (score 14):

This is now possible with [`@run-at document-start`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) and Firefox's [`beforescriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onbeforescriptexecute).  Tested only in FF24.

```
// ==UserScript==
...
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==

//a search string to uniquely identify the script
//for example, an anti-adblock script
var re = /adblock/i;

window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {

    if(re.test(e.target.text)){

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

}, true);
```

`beforescriptexecute` was [rejected](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/1103) for HTML 5 in 2016, and [Chrome is unlikely to implement it](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5711871906676736).

It does not run for `<script>` nodes inserted by other scripts.

Comment: +1 but note that this will work in FF only and has been supported since FF version 4.  Also, it might be better to use `.textContent` instead `.text` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Re:

> Is there some way I can define `window.devicePixelRatio` before the embedded script runs?

There is now.  Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Pre set devicePixelRatio
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @run-at   document-start
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
//-- @grant none is imporatant in this case.

window.devicePixelRatio = "Unimportant string or function or whatever";
```

---

---

**In the general case:**

Since Firefox version 4, this is now possible on Firefox only.  Use [the `checkForBadJavascripts` utility](https://gist.github.com/2620135) to leverage the power of `beforescriptexecute`. Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Block select inline JS
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2620135/checkForBadJavascripts.js
// @run-at   document-start
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

checkForBadJavascripts ( [
    [false, /window\.devicePixelRatio/, null]
] );
```

This blocks the *first* inline script, that contains `window.devicePixelRatio`, *entirely*.  If you want to selective modify parts of that script, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11201555/331508) and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472570/331508).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Privoxy instead of GreaseMonkey. You just use Privoxy as your proxy (on localhost) and search/replace the strings you don't like.