# Disabling a page's focus-checking function using GM?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm trying to stop a page from stopping itself when it thinks it's lost focus. So, how do I disable a function within a webpage using GM?

I'll try by giving the script on the page, hopefully someone can help me decipher it better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var domain = 'www.example.com';
var auto_surf = 1;
var sid = '51';
var hash = '55d99a37b2e1badba7c8df4ccd506a88';
var barsize = 1;
var maxbarsize = 250;
var numbercounter = 20;
var numbercounter_n = 20;
var adtimer = null;
var focusFlag = 1;
var fc_override = 0;
var fc_skip = 1;
var buster_listener = 1;
var buster = 0;
var buster_red = '?skip=51&bd';
var surf_file = 'surf.php';
var can_leave = false;
var report_msg1 = 'Please tell us why do you want to report this page:';
var report_msg2 = 'Page was successfully reported!';
var report_msg3 = 'An unexpected error occurred!';
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('4 7(a,b,c){8 e=9(f);g(e){$.h({i:"j",5:"k/l.m",n:o,p:"q="+a+"&5="+b+"&r="+c+"&s="+e,t:4(d){u(d){6\'1\':0(v);w(a,\'1\');3;6\'2\':0(x);3;y:0(z);3}}})}}',36,36,'alert|||break|function|url|case|report_page|var|prompt||||||report_msg1|if|ajax|type|POST|system|report|php|cache|false|data|id|module|reason|success|switch|report_msg2|skipuser|report_msg4|default|report_msg3'.split('|'),0,{}))
window.onbeforeunload = bust;
</script>
```

I already tried [Disabling a page's focus-checking function using GM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381421/disabling-a-pages-focus-checking-function-using-gm?answertab=active#tab-top), but it doesn't work for me!

I'm using Firefox 12 and GM v0.90; any help will be appreciated.

@BrockAdams here's the code:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('3 6(a){4(7.p)8 7.p(a);e 4(7.q)8 7.q[a];e 4(7.r)8 7.r[a]}$(7).X(3(){$(9).s("t",3(a){k=1}).s("Y",3(a){k=0})});3 u(){4(l!=1)8;v=w.m.x.Z(\'/\');4(v[2]!=10)8;9.c(3(){y++;4(y>5)8;4(11==1){w.m.12(13)}u()},1)}3 14(){9.c(3(){l=0},15)}3 16(){$(6(\'17\')).z(A);9.c(3(){$(6(\'f\')).B(\'C\')},D);9.c(3(){n()},18)}3 n(){4(g!=E){19(g);g=E}F a=h;4(7.G)a=7.G();e a=k;4(!a&&!1a){$(6(\'f\')).H();$(6(\'I\')).J()}e{$(6(\'f\')).J();$(6(\'I\')).H();4(d<=0){K();8}d-=0.5;4(d<0)d=0;i=1b.1c((1-(d/1d))*o);4(i>=o)i=o;6(\'1e\').1f=d.1g(1);6(\'1h\').1i.1j=i}g=9.c(3(){n()},1k)}3 K(){l=0;$(6(\'f\')).z(A);9.c(3(){$(6(\'1l\')).B(\'C\');4(1m==1){$.L({M:"N",O:"P/Q/R/S.T",j:"j="+U,V:3(a){W=h;7.m.x=1n+"?1o="+1p}})}e{$.L({M:"N",O:"P/Q/R/S.T",j:"1q=h&j="+U,V:3(a){W=h;$(\'#1r\').1s(a)}})}},D)}3 1t(a){F b=9.1u(a,\'1v\');b.t();8 1w}',62,95,'|||function|if||getObject|document|return|window|||setTimeout|numbercounter_n|else|timerdiv|adtimer|true|barsize|data|focusFlag|buster_listener|location|starttimer|maxbarsize|getElementById|layers|all|bind|focus|bust|tmp|top|href|buster|fadeOut|300|fadeIn|medium|400|null|var|hasFocus|hide|focusdiv|show|doverify|ajax|type|POST|url|system|modules|surf|process|php|sid|success|can_leave|ready|blur|split|domain|fc_skip|replace|buster_red|startbusterbreaker|10000|showtimer|loadingdiv|900|clearInterval|fc_override|Math|ceil|numbercounter|numbercounterspan|innerHTML|toFixed|progressbar|style|width|500|result_msg|auto_surf|surf_file|rand|hash|cpc|show_msg|html|openInNewWindow|open|_blank|false'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

thanks for your help

Comment: The code you show doesn't have anything to detect focus. Are you talking about clicking away from the tab or closing the tab/window?  **Link to the target page.**  Also it would be a good idea if you upgraded to the current version of FF and GM.  FF 12 was a lot of security exploits ago.

Comment: @Brock-Adams, yes thats it clicking away from the tab, and bypass the script that require that the tab or window must stay on focus, ty for fast reply

Comment: Okay. We still need to see the code that checks for focus -- especially if the linked Q didn't work.

Comment: @BrockAdams i added the code that check the focus.