# Too much recursion error using checkForBadJavascripts()

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm newbie to JS/Greasemonkey and have some difficulty debugging this script:

**N.B.:** The script parse the HTML of the site, find the SCRIPT tag and change the content of the script before it run.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        JustPaste.it CheckForBadScript
// @namespace   Mkhoul
// @description Test 01
// @include     https://justpaste.it/*
// @version     1
// @require https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12317-checkforbadjavascripts-js/code/checkForBadJavascriptsjs.js?version=73234
// @run-at document-start
// @grant GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==


/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox. MIKE MIKE MIKE
*/

function replaceTargetJavascript (scriptNode) {
    var scriptSrc   = scriptNode.textContent;
    scriptSrc       = scriptSrc.replace (
        "meta,script,object,applet,iframe,option,embed,span[size|face],pre,font[style|face],h2[style],h1[style],h3[style],h[style],input,textarea,submit",

        "dummyoption"
    );

    addJS_Node (scriptSrc);
}

checkForBadJavascripts ( [
    [false, /invalid_elements/, replaceTargetJavascript]
] );
```

It throw me in the console: "too much recursion"

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x6rj73t.png]

Then point to: https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12317-checkforbadjavascripts-js/code/checkForBadJavascriptsjs.js file

[image: http://i.imgur.com/F9agQMT.png]

.

The last error *"ReferenceError: initTinyMCE is not defined"* seem to be caused because of the first 2 errors.

`

From here: [How to alter this javascript with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200509/how-to-alter-this-javascript-with-greasemonkey) everything should work fine in the script.

**I don't see why I have those 2 "too much recursion" errors ?**

Answer (score 0):

`checkForBadJavascripts` adds an event listener `beforescriptexecute` that reacts to any script element being added, including those you add with addJS_node **while** the check is running. That's why the recursion is infinite.

To solve this you need to ensure first that a script contains the offending text using `indexOf`, for example. Only in that case replace it and add the script with `addJS_Node`.